# How do i change the background color of my website with HTML

Tags: html, html4

Help me,i need to change the color of the background of my website and i dont know how, I still haven't tried doing that because i dont know how.
I have only coded these lines:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <title>My first creations with coding!</title>
    </head>
   <body>
   <h1>My first creations with coding!</h1>  
     <br>
     <p>>like pro</p>


    
     
      </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's so basic it can be answered with a simple search but ironically it's so simple I could not even find a duplicate match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a Cascading Style Sheet or `.css` file my dude. You can read more about that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS).

Without reading that doc & overloading you with an insane amount of information... how can you set it up & get going?

1. In your website folder directory, add a new folder named `assets`
2. Within this new `assets` folder, create a new file named `style.css`
3. Attach this new `style.css` to your `html` file, within your `head` element. Using the following code :

   ```html
     <!DOCTYPE html> 
       <html>
         <head>
           <title>My first creations with coding!</title>
           <link src="/assets/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
         </head>
   ```
4. Save your 'html' file.
5. Open `style.css`
6. Add the following code :

   ```css
     body {
        background-color: black; /* change the 'black' color here ONLY */
     }
   ```

   List of [color keywords](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#color_keywords) if you scroll down.
7. Save the `css` file.
8. Refresh your browser.

Now just repeat steps 5-8 to change the background of your site.

Comment: The question asks how to do it with HTML. The answer to that question is, you can't.

Answer (score 0):

To change the background color, you need another coding language called **CSS** (cascading style sheets). You can implement it with a `<style> </style>` tag, and add CSS there, or add a separate file and link it like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="YOUR FILE HERE">
```

You can learn more about CSS [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp).

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <title>My first creations with coding!</title>
    </head>
   <body style="background-color:powderblue;">
   <h1>My first creations with coding!</h1>  
     <br>
     <p>>like pro</p>


    
     
      </body>
</html>
```